# Why changing a simple query parameter causes serious changes in MySQL query plan (explain)?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-indexes

I'm experiencing a strange situation with examining my query in MySQL using the "explain" command. I've got a table, which has three non-unique single column index on columns "Period","X", and "Y". All three of these columns have the same integer datatype. Then I examine the following commands:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Period = 201208 AND X >= 0 AND Y <= 454;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Period = 201304 AND X >= 0 AND Y <= 454;
```

The first one shows "Using index condition; Using where", but stangely the second onnly shows "Using where", so it seems like changing one parameter somehow eliminates indexes in query execution.

The table has about 65000 total rows, about 5000 per Period value (so it's balanced), and the first query returns about 2000 number of rows, the second returns about 500. Also, the latter period value (201304) is not the "last" physically in the table, and the former value is not the first as well, there are many rows with period values less and greater than this two specific.

My original table is quite complex with lots of columns, so I cannot paste it into here. But the only indexes are this three, and the query is the same as I used during testing, so I hope it should not matter too much.

Could someone give me any tip what can cause this and if I need to take care of something what I don!t know about? Thank you.